# Determine first cousins

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment where I was given the following:

```
male(albert).
male(edward).
male(fred).
male(steve).
male(jimmy).

female(alice).
female(victoria).
female(megan).
female(janet).
female(mary).

parents(edward,victoria,albert).
parents(alice,victoria,albert).
parents(fred,janet,steve).
parents(megan,janet,steve).

parents(victoria,mary,jimmy).
parents(steve,mary,jimmy).
```

From this, I need to write a function to determine if the pair of input people are first cousins. My attempt at this is below:

```
siblings(X,Y) :-
parents(X,M,F),
parents(Y,M,F).

firstCousin_Of(X,Y) :-
    parents(X,M,F),
    parents(Y,M2,F2),
    siblings(M,M2)
   ;   parents(X,M,F),
    parents(Y,M2,F2),
    siblings(M,F2)
   ;   parents(X,M,F),
    parents(Y,M2,F2),
    siblings(F,M2)
   ;   parents(X,M,F),
    parents(Y,M2,F2),
    siblings(F,F2).
```

This works, but it returns 'Singleton Variable' errors for M, M2, F, and F2.

Is there a cleaner way than what I wrote to determine the first cousin?

Comment: First cousins have the same grandparents.

Comment: I have to do this assignment without defining any more relationships. I need to be able to determine what a grandparent is by using the parental relationships.

Comment: Well, yes. Traditionally, in continental Europe, the parents of the parents are the grandparents. I am not an anthropologist though.

Comment: Make life a little easier and try to define a `grandparent` predicate, and then define your `first_cousins` based upon that instead of "inlining" the grandparent logic.